# Struggling with filtering Drupal data in Gatsby GraphQL query

Tags: drupal, graphql, gatsby

I am using Drupal 8 JSON:API to expose data to my Gatsby site. I have built a GraphQL query to expose a list of "officers" which contains a field with a relationship to a set of "service periods". The data returned by the API is correct, but I would like to filter for only one specific child record (service period) and can not figure out how to do that. My query is:

```
  officerList: allGroupContentLodgeGroupNodeOfficer(filter: {relationships: {entity_id: {relationships: {field_position: {elemMatch: {relationships: {field_service_period: {drupal_internal__tid: {eq: 203}}}}}}}}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        r: relationships {
          entity_id {
            r: relationships {
              field_position {
                r: relationships {
                  field_position {
                    name
                  }
                  field_service_period {
                    name
                    drupal_internal__tid
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            title
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The resulting JSON set is:

```
  "data": {
    "officerList": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "r": {
              "entity_id": {
                "r": {
                  "field_position": [
                    {
                      "r": {
                        "field_position": {
                          "name": "Governor"
                        },
                        "field_service_period": {
                          "name": "2018 - 2019",
                          "drupal_internal__tid": 203
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "r": {
                        "field_position": {
                          "name": "Junior Past Governor"
                        },
                        "field_service_period": {
                          "name": "2019 - 2020",
                          "drupal_internal__tid": 204
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                "title": "Tom Jones"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I understand the resulting set is correct because the child is within the root. However, I can not see how to filter the full query to include only certain child records. Is this even possible? I have seen some implementations of GraphQL that seem to allow filters to be placed on children, but I don't think this is possible in Gatsby.

I have searched everywhere for possible solutions and have been banging my head against the wall for a few days. Any insight is GREATLY appreciated!

TIA!

Comment: graphql is not for filtering ... graphql is for pass filtering requirements to API and get filtered data

Comment: Filtering is part of the GraphQL spec.

Comment: defined where ?

Comment: My apologies. I meant the Gatsby spec. I'm trying to figure out how to filter a child record using a GraphQL request in Gatsby to the API.